# Wrong output in Python - as per my logic

Tags: python, list, quicksort

Can someone tell me why my program is working weird. I am trying to sort `list1` in ascending order. This code is part of my quick sort program I am trying to write. As per my logic which I am applying in this code, and I checked manually too, the output should be [1,2,3,4,5]. However the output is coming out to be [1,2,2,4,5]. Can you tell what's going wrong?

```
list1=[3,2,1,5,4]
n_list1=len(list1)
count=0

for position1, item1 in enumerate(list1[0:n_list1]):
    temp=item1
    count=count+1
    for position2 in range(count,n_list1):
        if list1[position1]>list1[position2]:
            list1[position1]=list1[position2]
            list1[position2]=temp
            temp=list1[position1]
print list1
```

**EDIT:** What I am trying to do is like this:

I start comparing the first element with the following (n-1) elements and swap the smallest element with the first one. Now I go to 2nd element and compare it with the following (n-2) elements and swap with the smallest element among those (n-2) elements. Like this I move forward.

**Note:** This is part of my quicksort program and it is not in itself quicksort. This part is for the `list1` to which I assign numbers less than pivot. Another code will be for `list2` where I will assign numbers greater than pivot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer provided by rbp is absolutely correct!

Also, I guess you could simplify the above by remove count itself, also directly enumerate the list and use the python idiom - a, b = b, a to swap the values

```
list1=[3,2,1,6,5,4]
n_list1 = len(list1)
for position1, item1 in enumerate(list1):
    for position2 in range(position1,n_list1):
        if list1[position1]>list1[position2]:
            list1[position1] , list1[position2] = list1[position2], list1[position1]
print list1
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

[Edit: About the idiom]

```
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 5
>>> a , b  = b, a
>>> a
5
>>> b
4
>>> c  = 5
>>> d = 6
>>> t = c
>>> c = d
>>> d = t 
>>> c
6
>>> d
5
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you do `count = count + 1` right before the innermost `for`, you never get to reach the first position of list1 (`list1[0]`), which is the element "3".

[Edit] Looking more carefully at your code, there seems to be a lot of confusion. For instance, on

```
        list1[position1]=list1[position2]
        list1[position2]=temp
        temp=list1[position1]
```

You're losing list1[position1]: you're overwriting it with list[position2], before trying to save it at the temp variable. Try moving `temp=list1[position1]` to the first line after the `if`.

And, honestly, your implementation is overly complicated. I suggest you try writing it in pseudo-code, try to actually understand what's going on, and then re-implement it.

Comment: That doesn't do what you're thinking it does. As I've mentioned on my edit, you're jumping through too many hoops. Take a look at Jon Bentley's implementation, is very clean and should make you understand quicksort better: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMnn0Jq0J-E (it's also on the "Beautiful Code" book, if you have access to it)

Comment: Another minor point: enumerate(list1[0:len(list1)]) is basically the same thing as enumerate(list1).

Comment: What I am trying to do is like this: I start comparing the first element with the following (n-1) elements and swap the smallest element with the first one. Now I go to 2nd element and compare it with the following (n-2) elements and swap with the smallest element among those (n-2) elements. Like this I move forward.

Comment: This is (kind of) a bubble sort, not a quick sort!

Comment: rbp is correct that you are clobbering temp, in the second for loop.  To see what is happening use this as your list list1=[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] and look at your results.  Move the temp line to the first item in your if block and things work, properly.

Comment: Well, it will be a very weird quicksort. On quicksort, you don't need to explicitly *sort* each sublist.; just throw numbers less than pivot to one side, greater than pivot to the other, and recursively call quicksort on each side. As I said before, you're just making yourself confused with a very roundabout implementation. I suggest you start fresh, with pseudo-code (and read more about quicksort). Also, look at the changes I (and Philip) suggested.

Answer (score 0):

A small improvement to pyfunc's correct answer...
This line

```
for position2 in range(position1,n_list1)
```

can be

```
for position2 in range(position1+1,n_list1)
```

and will save you a little time.